# Why am I getting NotImplementedError with async and await on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have this code:

```
import os
import time
import asyncio


async def run_command(*args):
    """
    Example from:
        http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html
    """
    # Create subprocess
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args,
        # stdout must a pipe to be accessible as process.stdout
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

    # Result
    result = stdout.decode().strip()

    # Return stdout
    return result


def run_asyncio_commands(tasks):
    """Run tasks using asyncio and return results"""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    commands = asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # Unpack list using *
    results = loop.run_until_complete(commands)
    loop.close()
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()

    cmds = [
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Desktop'],
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik'],
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Pictures']
    ]

    tasks = []
    for cmd in cmds:
        tasks.append(run_command(*cmd))
    results = run_asyncio_commands(tasks)
    print(results)

    end = time.time()
    print('Script ran in', str(end - start), 'seconds')
```

When I run the that code in Python 3.6.1 on my mac, I get this:

```
['780K\t/Users/fredrik/Desktop', '46G\t/Users/fredrik', '52M\t/Users/fredrik/Pictures']
Script ran in 6.405519008636475 seconds
```

But when I run the same script on Windows (but with the `du` commands substituted to something which works on Windows), also with Python 3.6.1, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iruser\Desktop\asynciotest.py", line 66, in <module>
    results = run_asyncio_commands(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\iruser\Desktop\asynciotest.py", line 41, in run_asyncio_commands
    results = loop.run_until_complete(commands)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\condaenvs\dev_py36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\iruser\Desktop\asynciotest.py", line 16, in run_command
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\condaenvs\dev_py36\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 225, in create_subprocess_exec
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\condaenvs\dev_py36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1190, in subprocess_exec
    bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\condaenvs\dev_py36\lib\asyncio\coroutines.py", line 210, in coro
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\condaenvs\dev_py36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 340, in _make_subprocess_transp
ort
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

This is what I substitute the Unix commands with on Windows:

```
cmds = [['C:/Windows/system32/HOSTNAME.EXE']]
```

Python and Windows version info:

```
Python 3.6.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 23 2017, 14:21:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Windows 10 Pro, version 1703, OS build 15063.413
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Different event loops are implemented differently. Some of them have restrictions (sometimes OS-related). By default, Windows uses [SelectorEventLoop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.SelectorEventLoop) and as you can see in [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html#windows):

> SelectorEventLoop has the following limitations:
>
> - SelectSelector is used to wait on socket events: it supports sockets and is limited to 512 sockets.
> - loop.add_reader() and loop.add_writer() only accept socket handles (e.g. pipe file descriptors are not supported).
> - Pipes are not supported, so the loop.connect_read_pipe() and loop.connect_write_pipe() methods are not implemented.
> - Subprocesses are not supported, i.e. loop.subprocess_exec() and loop.subprocess_shell() methods are not implemented.

To run your code in Windows you can use alternative event loop available by default - `ProactorEventLoop`.

Replace line:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

with this:

```
loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Your code will work.

Comment: By adding: asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

Comment: How can I use the ProactorEventLoop when running tests with pytest and pytest-asyncio?

Comment: To the question in my comment above @pytest.fixture \n def event_loop(request): \n loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() \n yield loop \n loop.close()

Comment: @Brent you should probably create a custom `event_loop`. Take a look here - https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio#event_loop

Comment: this did not work for me - i added the two lines from the solution and the policy from Jordan and it still says `NotImplementedError` for `loop.add_reader`

Answer (score 6):

3.7.0 Python documentation handles this here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html#asyncio-windows-subprocess

Set the event loop policy if you are using Windows - then your code will work.

In your startup, change the unix-specific section:

```
cmds = [
    ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Desktop'],
    ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik'],
    ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Pictures']
]
```

to handle Windows & Unix:

```
if 'win32' in sys.platform:
    # Windows specific event-loop policy & cmd
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())
    cmds = [['C:/Windows/system32/HOSTNAME.EXE']]
else:
    # Unix default event-loop policy & cmds
    cmds = [
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Desktop'],
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik'],
        ['du', '-sh', '/Users/fredrik/Pictures']
    ]
```

Comment: Note that [`WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy` and `WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy` were added in Python 3.7 first](https://bugs.python.org/issue33792), so setting default policy won't work with Python 3.6 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This has a GitHub issue page [https://github.com/saghul/aiodns/issues/86][1]

The latest addition is a suggestion to add the following:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in python and ipython, it seems the loop can be change in python, but not in ipython, and I also found the default loop is `` in jupyter and can not change neither.

**Tests in python**

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>python
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
<asyncio.windows_events.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy object at 0x0000018054ACC790>
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop()
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
<ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
>>> asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
<asyncio.windows_events.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy object at 0x0000018054A8E0E0>
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop()
<_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
>>> exit()

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

**Tests in ipython**

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>ipython
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import asyncio

In [2]: asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
Out[2]: <asyncio.windows_events.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy at 0x1df598b7e20>

In [3]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-3-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
Out[3]: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

In [4]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-4-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
Out[4]: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

In [5]: asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

In [6]: asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
Out[6]: <asyncio.windows_events.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy at 0x1df59a6c820>

In [7]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-7-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
Out[7]: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

In [8]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-8-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
Out[8]: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

In [9]: asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.SelectorEventLoop())

In [10]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-10-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
Out[10]: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

In [11]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter on Windows uses "SelectorEventLoop", to make `asyncio.subprocess` work you [must use "ProactorEventLoop"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html#subprocess-support-on-windows) but there's no way to do it.

There's [GitHub's issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/391) [(2)](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6882) that's been open since 2019, and it probably won't get fixed anytime soon [(1)](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/669) [(2)](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12545).

However I managed to run a docker process asynchronously from jupyter using `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess


async def run_docker(args: list[str]):
    def run():
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["docker"]
            + args,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True,
        )

        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        if stderr:
            raise Exception(stderr)

        return stdout

    return await asyncio.to_thread(run)
```

Personally, I find it quite disappointing that as of 2023, the Python ecosystem still lacks a strong and universally adopted method for running processes asynchronously. Even JavaScript managed to address this issue quite a while back.