# asyncio create_subprocess_shell python 3.7 on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test some asyncio functionality on Windows. I'm using Python 3.7.

This complains bitterly about some NotImplementedError

```
import asyncio
import os
import time
import sys

#this works
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

#this doesn't
async def test_async(num):
    print('Task #{0} start'.format(num))

    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        'C:/Python37/python test_repl.py',
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE )

    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate("sleep 10")
    cmd = 'python'
    print(f'[{cmd!r} exited with {proc.returncode}]')
    if stdout:
        print(f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode()}')
    if stderr:
        print(f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode()}')

async def test_loop():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        test_async(1))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        test_async(2))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
asyncio.run(test_loop())
```

I've tried several loop types (Protractor and Default). I've tried different functions through the shell and directly invoking the program (_shell and _exec in the subprocess lingo). Nothing seems to work. For a much hype I've read about asyncio, it can't possibly be a Linux only thing. I must be doing something wrong. Can you please point me in the right direction.

The specific error I get is the following:

```
--------------Async--------------------
started at 22:39:55
Task #1 start
Task #2 start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multirun.py", line 45, in <module>
    asyncio.run(test_loop())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "multirun.py", line 38, in test_loop
    await task1
  File "multirun.py", line 20, in test_async
    stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 202, in create_subprocess_shell
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1486, in subprocess_shell
    protocol, cmd, True, stdin, stdout, stderr, bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 444, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<test_async() done, defined at multirun.py:12> exception=NotImplementedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multirun.py", line 20, in test_async
    stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 202, in create_subprocess_shell
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1486, in subprocess_shell
    protocol, cmd, True, stdin, stdout, stderr, bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 444, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Also, I got the same error when trying to run the notepad.

Comment: Can you show the resulting exception and the traceback? Does `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` work when you execute some other command?

Comment: @user4815162342 I've edited the question a little bit with the information about the specific error I'm getting.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not actually using the `ProactorEventLoop`, despite appearances. `asyncio.run()` creates a *new* event loop based on the current loop creation policy, which you've never changed. (The [documentation[(https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) example frankly looks incompatible with `asyncio.run`.) Try replacing `asyncio.run(test_loop())` with `loop.run_until_complete(test_loop())` and see if that helps.

Comment: @user4815162342: that worked! Do you mind putting that as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Note that asyncio.create_subprocess_shell() is not implemented for Windows cmd shell as of python version 3.7.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Why am I getting NotImplementedError with async and await on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633458/why-am-i-getting-notimplementederror-with-async-and-await-on-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Python 3.8, this issue should no longer exist, as the proactor event loop is now the [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html#asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy) event loop on Windows. Original answer follows below.

---

The problem is that, despite appearances, you're not actually using the `ProactorEventLoop`. [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) creates a new event loop based on the current loop creation policy, which you've never changed. Creating a new loop for each run is normally a feature because it guarantees cleanup of the resources associated with the loop - but in this case it's incompatible with the [example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) from the documentation. (Edit: the example has since been [removed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) because `ProactorEventLoop` was made the default.)

A quick fix is to change `asyncio.run(test_loop())` to `loop.run_until_complete(test_loop())`. A better fix is to [set the event loop policy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html#asyncio.set_event_loop_policy) to one that creates the proactor loop.

Comment: The link provided for `set the event loop policy` is broken, however I believe it was linking to this content: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-policy.html

Comment: @bicarlsen Fixed the link, thanks. The idea was to directly link to the docs of the `set_event_loop_policy` method.