# asyncio.create_subprocess_exec can't run in Windows? (batch script)

Tags: python, windows, python-asyncio, python-3.7

```
def run_safe(self, cmd):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        cmd = 'cmd /c ' + cmd
    ret_code = asyncio.run(self.coroutine_out_stream(cmd))
    return ret_code


async def coroutine_out_stream(cmd):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
                                                   stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                   stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
    stderr = stderr.decode('utf-8')

    ret_code = process.returncode
    cmd = SubProcBatch.cmd_to_string(cmd)
    cmd = SubProcBatch.encrypt_password(cmd)
    print('cmd :' + cmd)
    print(stdout.strip())
    print(stderr.strip())
    print('process.returncode : ' + str(process.returncode))
    return stdout, stderr, ret_code
```

This code works normally when the bash script is inserted into the cmd on the Mac. But in Windows batch script is not running.

Can I run a batch script using `create_subprocess_exec` in Windows?
Error message is "NotImplementedError". What is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio create\_subprocess\_shell python 3.7 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127248/asyncio-create-subprocess-shell-python-3-7-on-windows)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633458/why-am-i-getting-notimplementederror-with-async-and-await-on-windows

Comment: According to that link, "create_subprocess_exe" is not executed in Windows, right?

Comment: According to the link you need to use a `ProactorEventLoop` in order to use `create_subprocess_exec` in Windows (which becomes the default in Python 3.8).