# Running a script through subprocess hangs when script runs an asyncio eventloop inside multiprocessing workers

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, subprocess

Running Python 3.7.3 on Windows,

I have a situation where an `asyncio` event loop never breaks out of a process spawn from multiprocessing. I can't show all the code, but it's like this:

1. I use `multiprocessing` to speed up queries using an third-party
   API.
2. This API `thirdparty.api` supports a server-client architecture and uses asyncio
   event loop internally. It runs an event loop in a separate thread; in that thread, it calls `event_loop.run_forever()` and breaks only on `KeyboardInterrupt`.
3. Run the worker script using multiprocessing, the API always returns, be it success or failure. Previously I hit a Py3.7.2 regression where on Windows the venv Python executable works in a bad way https://bugs.python.org/issue35797. But now that is fixed in Py3.7.3 and my problem persists.
4. Running this script from another Py27 script using `subprocess`. Inside my multiprocessing worker process, if the query failed, the call never returns and it couldn't break out of the worker process naturally, even a generic exception handler won't catch anything and will get stuck.

code snippets of my caller script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

def main()
    try:
        cmd = ['C:\\Python\\Python37\\pythonw.exe', 'worker.py']
        print(' '.join(cmd))
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        print(err)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        print('try popen finished with else.')
    print('stdout: {}'.format(out))
    print('stderr: {}'.format(err))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pseudo-code snippets of my worker `worker.py` function look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

args = [
   ...
]


def worker(*mpargs):
    with thirdparty.api() as myclient:
        try:
            myclient.query(*args)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()


def exception_worker(*mpargs)
    raise RuntimeError('Making trouble!')


def main():
    logging.info('STARTED!')
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, args)
        # results = pool.map(exception_worker, args)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    logging.info('ALL DONE!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

thirdparty.api starts event loop in its constructor:

```
self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
if self.loop.is_closed():
    self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
```

then in its separate thread:

```
try:
    self._loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
self.loop.close()
```

I've tried another worker `exception_worker` which just throws exceptions, and this one returns without issues.

How should I solve this?

Comment: More details, please. How do you use `multiprocessing`? And `myclient.query` looks like a normal function instead of an asynchronous one.

Comment: @Sraw Thanks for the tip. I added more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After detailing the issue, I finally found the solution in this post:
[Why am I getting NotImplementedError with async and await on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633458/why-am-i-getting-notimplementederror-with-async-and-await-on-windows)

The `thirdparty.api` needed to attend to this detail and after fixing it, my problem is gone.