# Python raises NotImplementedError when trying to call shell command with asyncio subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am new with Python programming. I want to call a few shell commands in parallel and get their result accumulated in a single array just like javascript `promise.all()` method.

I have the following code in Python:

```
import asyncio
import os


commands = [
    'netstat -n | findstr 55601',
    'dir | findstr portMonitoring.py',
    'ssh 10.6.100.192 netstat'
]

async def job(cmd):
    # await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # return "HEE"
    # return os.popen(cmd).read()
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    return await process.communicate()



async def main():
    jobs = [job(cmd) for cmd in commands]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(jobs, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    folders = []
    [folders.append(d.result()) for d in done]
    print("RESULT:", folders)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in job
    cmd, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
  File "C:\DEV\Python3.7.4\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 217, in create_subprocess_exec
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "C:\DEV\Python3.7.4\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1529, in subprocess_exec
    bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "C:\DEV\Python3.7.4\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 458, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: I would try to install python 3.8 (in a virtualenv or through conda) and try with that. I suppose you are trying to use a feature that was not implemented with 3.7.4 yet

Comment: I can't directly reproduce your error, as I don't have 3.7 at hand right now, but here's what I found out: Pasting your code at the 3.8 console at https://www.python.org/shell/ shows a different error without showing the RESULT line. However, I see that line if I replace `create_subprocess_exec` with `create_subprocess_shell`, I also get errors but now see the RESULT line. Have you tried that already? The documentation is not really clear to me on which one you should use...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L493

It's a planned feature but it is not implemented yet. It will work in the future but the current versions don't support it.

I looked through the other branches and none of them are implemented. The subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is widely known and the `asyncio` support for it is not yet finished. The endpoints were defined but they are as of now not usable.

Comment: IMHO this answer is incorrect. `base_events.py` contains a base class, which is overriden in `windows_events.py` and `unix_events.py`. If a method is not implemented in the base class, it does not mean it is not implemented at all. Or could you link any source for the claim "it is planned, but not implemented yet"?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the docs:

#### Python 3.7

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-platforms.html#asyncio-windows-subprocess

> SelectorEventLoop on Windows does not support subproceses. On Windows,
>   ProactorEventLoop should be used instead:

```
import asyncio

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(
    asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(your_code())
```

#### Python 3.8

The default event loop on Windows is now the ProactorEventLoop.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Jupyter thus you can't switch to ProactorEventLoop, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981596/1951947

Here an example to run the docker process:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

async def run_docker(args: list[str]):
    def run():
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["docker"]
            + args,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True,
        )

        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        if stderr:
            raise Exception(stderr)

        return stdout

    return await asyncio.to_thread(run)
```

Comment: Please review [answer]