# Using asyncio to run command in a time interval and terminate it afterwards

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-os

I'm excuting a shell command by `os.system()`. I planned to run it for 1 second, then terminate it if time exceeded. Here's what I tried instead as a test.

```py
import os, time, asyncio

async def cmd():
    os.system("my.py > my.txt") # this processes longer than 1 second

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    try:
        yield from asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), 1) # this should excute for more than 1 sec, and hence raise TimeoutError
        print("A")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        os.system("killall python")
        print("B")
    
asyncio.run(run())
```

But the result was always "A" and the txt was written by my.py.

I also tried:

```py
import os, time, asyncio

async def cmd():
    os.system("my.py > my.txt") # longer than 1 sec

async def run():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), 1) # should raise TimeoutError
        print("A")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        os.system("killall python")
        print("B")
    
asyncio.run(run())
```

results in the same output.
What's wrong with the code? I'm pretty new to asyncio and never used it before. Thanks in advance. It's most likely not the problem that `wait_for` does not stop the cast automatically, since I have a `killall python` in the second part and in fact, the wait_for function never raises the timeout error, that's the problem.

Comment: `cmd` contains two blocking commands. It never yields back control to the event loop which I believe is necessary for the loop to kill your task. Does using `await asyncio.sleep(2)` change the result? It it does, this won't really solve your problem, but it should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @dirn What does `yield from` here does? And by the way, the original `cmd()` function contains only 1 line, that is, the `os.system()` line which should run over 1 second. The purpose of `time.sleep(2)` here is just to make sure that the function runs over 1 second.

Comment: The `yield from` does the same thing as the `await` in your second version. `asyncio.coroutine` has been deprecated in favor of the dedicated `async`/`await` syntax so you should use the second version.

Comment: I figured your real code didn't include the sleep; that's why I said awaiting the asyncio version wouldn't really solve your problem. If it fixed this specific version of `cmd`, though, it would indicate that using something asyncio-aware instead of `os.system` would potentially accomplish what you want.

Comment: @dirn So setting a timeout for asyncio.wait_for doesn't work here?

Comment: Probably not to stop `os.system`. You might have luck with `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`, but I’m not sure if that will kill the subprocess or just the task that’s controlling it.

Comment: @dirn I mean, os.system("killall python") will probably do the job, but the problem here is that it will always print "A", not to even process the `except` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228350/discussion-between-acc-lab-and-dirn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` is a blocking operation, so it doesn't play well with `asyncio`. Whenever you use `asyncio`, all "longer" operations need to be asynchronous, or you lose all benefits of going with `asyncio` in the first place.

```
import asyncio

async def cmd():
    try:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
            "sleep 2 && date > my.txt",
            shell=True,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL)
        await proc.communicate()

    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        proc.terminate()
        print("X")

async def run():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), 1)
        print("A")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("B")

asyncio.run(run())
```

As @dim mentions in comments, `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` will launch an external command asynchronously. `wait_for` will actually raise two exceptions: `TimeoutError` in the awaiting code, and `CancelledError` in the awaited code. We can use the latter to realise the operation was cancelled, and to `terminate` or `kill` our subprocess (as this is not done automatically).

Comment: The code is giving me `NotImplementedError`

Comment: The code I posted runs correctly as-is on at least python3.7 and python3.8 under Mac OS X (and almost certainly Linux as well). If you are having issues with it, please report the Python version as well as the exact line where the error happens, and I will look into it.

Comment: Which python version, which OS, which line of my code fits in one line though.

Comment: File "C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\a.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run()) / 
    return loop.run_until_complete(main) / 
    return future.result() / 
    await asyncio.wait_for(cmd(), 1) / 
    return fut.result() / 
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL) / 
    stderr=stderr, **kwds) / 
    protocol, cmd, True, stdin, stdout, stderr, bufsize, **kwargs) / 
The last line: 
  File "C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 458, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Comment: So, Windows. I am not an expert on Windows programming, but I am almost certain this is the source (and possibly solution) of the problem: [Why am I getting NotImplementedError with async and await on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633458/why-am-i-getting-notimplementederror-with-async-and-await-on-windows)